# How do I solve "incompatible numba" error while installing Scanpy?

Tags: python, anaconda, scanpy

I tried installing the Scanpy package on Jupyter with "pip install Scanpy" but I got the the errors below;

**ERROR: pynndescent 0.5.2 has requirement numba>=0.51.2, but you'll have numba 0.48.0 which is incompatible. ERROR: umap-learn 0.5.1 has requirement numba>=0.49, but you'll have numba 0.48.0 which is incompatible**

When I tried to separately install an upgraded version of numba, I got the error below;

**ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'llvmlite'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Run `pip install --upgrade numba`
2. Run `pip install scanpy`

Answer (score 0):

you can try install with pip install -c numba numba=0.51.2.1rc1 if it doesn't work for you alternativly install RUN pip install llvmlite --ignore installed before pip install numba.
HAVE A GOOD DAY:)